# Column names of data frame into list

Tags: r

I have a data frame with over 700 columns.  I wondered if there was any way of creating a new table with a list of these column names and their corresponding column number that I can refer back to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 data.frame(col_no = 1:ncol(iris), variable = names(iris))
  col_no     variable
1      1 Sepal.Length
2      2  Sepal.Width
3      3 Petal.Length
4      4  Petal.Width
5      5      Species
```

Comment: Entered this but doesn't seem to work.... any suggestions please?  ```meta2_CD_colnames <- meta2_CD(col_no = 1:ncol(meta2_CD), variable = names(meta2_CD))```

Comment: try `meta2_CD_colnames <- data.frame(col_no = 1:ncol(meta2_CD), variable = names(meta2_CD))`

Answer (score 0):

you can also store the names in a named list:

```
col_names <- names(df)

names(col_names) <- 1:length(col_names)


output:
 1   2   3 
"x" "y" "c"
```